# How to copy one object from a vector to another vector in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures

I have a Product class which represents a single product object, each new Product object is stored inside a vector that is part of the Catalog class. I want the user to be able to add products that exist inside the catalog vector to his shopping cart, which is another class that has a vector to save the products he wants to order. I want this to be done by copying from the Catalog vector to the shopping cart vector.

**Product class**

```
class Product
{
    private:
        // int id;
        // Category category;
        std::string name;
        std::string description;
        float price;
        unsigned short int stock; 

    public:
        Product(std::string name, std::string description, float price, 
                unsigned short int stock);

        void setId(int id);
        // void setCategory(Category category);
        void setName(std::string name);
        void setDescription(std::string description);
        void setPrice(float price);
        void setStock(unsigned short int stock);

        int getId();
        // Category getCategory();
        std::string getName();
        std::string getDescription();
        float getPrice();
};
```

**Catalog class**

```
class Catalog 
{
    // friend class ShoppingCart;

    private:
        std::vector<Product> catalog;
        std::vector<Product>::iterator it;

    public:
        /**
         * TODO: The createProduct(), deleteProduct() and updateProduct() method should only be accessible by the admin user
         */

        std::vector<Product> getCatalog();
        // add product to catalog -> admin
        void productCreate(Product p);
        // delete product from catalog -> admin
        void productDelete(std::string name);
        // update a product -> admin
        void productUpdate(std::string &name);
        // list products inside catalog

        void productList();
        // search products 
        bool productSearch(std::string name);

};
```

**ShoppingCart class**

```
class ShoppingCart
{   
    private:
        // vector that contains products to order
        std::vector<Product> shoppingCart;
        Catalog catalog;
        // int quantity;

    public:
        void cartList();
        int cartSize();
        void addToCart(std::string);
        void deleteFromCart(std::string);
        void clearCart();
};
```

Since this project is text based (terminal), I want the user to be able to add the product to his shopping cart by typing the product name. My logic for this can be seen in the code below:

**addToCart method from ShoppingCart class**

```
void ShoppingCart::addToCart(string name)
{   
    /** 
     * BUG: Doesnt add objects to the shoppingcart vector
     */

    for (Product p : catalog.getCatalog())
    {
        if (p.getName() == name) {
            shoppingCart.push_back(p);
        } else {
            printf("Oops.. %s doesn't seem to exist in our catalog.",
                    name.c_str());
        }
    }
}
```

**View that receives the user input**

```
void View::shoppingcart()
{
    string productName;

    cout << "Add to cart: ";
    cin >> productName;

    cart.addToCart(productName);

    printf("You added '%s'", productName.c_str());

    cout << endl;
}
```

when I execute this code no errors are given but the nothing actually gets added to the shopping cart vector, size stays at 0. What am doing wrong? Or am I missing something here? Keep in mind that im new to C++ programming.

Comment: do you see "Oops.. %s doesn't seem to exist in our catalog." message?

Comment: My ESP is telling me you copy your `Catalog` object to your `ShoppingCart` object before you've added any `Product`s to it, but the code you've posted isn't sufficient to tell for sure.  A [mcve] could help.

Comment: @Raffallo Sorry I wanted to mention that in post, but no it never goes to that part.So no error or any indication of something that I am doing wrong is given.

Comment: There is a member `Catalog catalog` in `class ShoppingCart`. Is this really the catalog of all products available in your shop? If not, you try to copy from a local member which probably is always empty. I'm afraid something is broken in your concept...

Comment: @MilesBudnek Hmmm, strange. I dont work with any databases right now but I always add a product to my catalog first before i test adding to the shopping cart.

Comment: @ManuFebie so the guys above are right :) you keep whole `Catalog` in `ShoppingCart` class, and never fill it with data. I think that you should change your concept and add a method to `Catalog` class, ie.: `bool GetItem(string name, Product& outProduct)` and if it will return `true` you will add product by method `void addToCart(Product product);`

Comment: @Scheff, Ah yeah, never realized that. I will take look at that part tonight when im home again. If that is the case I will close this issue.

Comment: @Raffallo Thank you, I will try that tonight here.

Comment: Assuming, you grant that life-time of `Catalog catalog` is longer than that of any `ShoppingCart` instance, you could do the following: Change `Catalog catalog` in `class ShoppingCart` to `Catalog &catalog` i.e. a reference. You have to initialize it in constructor of `class ShoppingCart` with the "global" catalog. Hence, each shopping cart could use it's reference member to access the global catalog.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet at [Compiler explorer](godbolt.org), so we can play around with it?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I did wrong. As pointed out by @scheff, I had `Catalog catalog` as an class member for my ShoppingCart. However in my View class I already have an instance of Catalog. I totally lost my train of thought after leaving this project for two weeks hehe, so my bad. So to make sure I get the object from the catalog I modified the addToCart method by adding an extra param: `addToCart(string name, Catalog catalog)`.

**Snippet**:

```cpp
// ShoppingCart.cpp
void ShoppingCart::addToCart(string name, Catalog catalog)
{
    for (Product p : catalog.getCatalog())
    {
        if (p.getName() == name) {
            shoppingCart.push_back(p);
        }
    }
}
```

```
// View.cpp
void View::shoppingcart()
{
    // Allows user to add product to shopping cart.
    string productName;
    // int quantity;

    while (productName != "q")
    {   
        cout << "Cart : " << cart.cartSize() << " item(s)" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Enter product name to add to cart or enter 'q' to quit : ";
        cin >> productName;

        cart.addToCart(productName, catalog);
        // cart.addToCart(productName, quantity, catalog);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the feedback.